# Give an example of a lattice in which every element (except 0, 1) has four complements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Is there any lattice in which every element (except $0$ and $1$) has four complements?

Is the set {1,2,3,5,7,11,2310} under the relation divides a correct example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of answer supplied by others is quite obviously correct. If you want a more "synthetic" description, consider the lattice of vector subspaces of the 2-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_4$-vector space $\mathbb{F}_4^2$ (where $\mathbb{F}_4$ is the field with four elements).

Comment: Is the set {1,2,3,5,7,11,2310} under the relation "divides" an example?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Can please help me in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509919/for-what-values-of-n-the-set-of-divisors-of-n-under-partial-order-relation-divid

Comment: I'm tempted to ask you to ask user18921 for help, since you accepted his/her answer as correct. But perhaps I'll take a look.

Comment: Everyone's answer is correct. I just accepted user18921's answer because it was easier to understand. I did voted your answer as useful. But I have ticked ur answer as correct now as u answered one more question.

Comment: @user221458, no sweat, I don't care about points anyway.

Comment: @user18921 Can u please help me on this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509919/for-what-values-of-n-the-set-of-divisors-of-n-under-partial-order-relation-divid

Comment: @user221458, I would, if I knew the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, it would be best to write $\bot$ for the least element and $\top$ for the greatest.

Let $L = \{\bot,0,1,2,3,4,\top\},$ and define $$x \leq y \leftrightarrow x = \bot \mbox{ or } y = \top.$$

Then $(L,\leq)$ is a lattice in which every element except for $\bot$ and $\top$ has four complements.

To see this, draw a diagram, and try computing the meet and join of $0$ and $1$ (say).

Answer (score 3):

Take $L = \{0, 1, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 \}$ with the partial order defined by $0 < x_i < 1$
for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant 5$. Then for $i \not= j$, $x_i$ and $x_j$ are complements of each other. Therefore every element of $L$ (except $0$ and $1$) have four complements.